# Не могу создать на печатную форму BAF Версия 8.3.12

Tags: 1с

Добрий день я новичок в 1С
Мне на работе дали форму документа нужно создать кнопку для вывода его на печать данные реквизитов,я занесь так же дал условия двум реквизитам вроде все делаю правильно, но все равно ошибка при клики на кнопку печать.
***Ошибка***

```
    {Документ.Командировка.Команда.Командировка.МодульКоманды(53,42)}: Змінна не визначена (Должность)
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Должность" = <<?>>Должность); (Перевірка: Сервер)
{Документ.Командировка.Команда.Командировка.МодульКоманды(54,39)}: Змінна не визначена (Звание)
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Звание" = <<?>>Звание); (Перевірка: Сервер)
{Документ.Командировка.Команда.Командировка.МодульКоманды(55,46)}: Змінна не визначена (Подразделение)
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Подразделение" = <<?>>Подразделение); (Перевірка: Сервер)
```

Вот мой полностю модуль

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОбработкаКоманды(ПараметрКоманды, ПараметрыВыполненияКоманды)
   
ТабДок = Новый ТабличныйДокумент; 

ПечятьНаСервере(ТабДок);

ТабДок.Показать("Командировка");

КонецПроцедуры

&Насервере
Процедура ПечятьНаСервере(ТабДок)    
       //{{КОНСТРУКТОР_ЗАПРОСА_С_ОБРАБОТКОЙ_РЕЗУЛЬТАТА
   // Даний фрагмент побудований конструктором.
   // При повторному використанні конструктора, внесені вручну зміни будуть втрачені!!!
   
   Запрос = Новый Запрос;
   Запрос.Текст = 
       "ВЫБРАТЬ
       |   Командировка.Номер КАК Номер,
       |   Командировка.Дата КАК Дата
       |ИЗ
       |   Документ.Командировка КАК Командировка
       |;
       |
       |////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       |ВЫБРАТЬ
       |   Командировка.Сотрудник КАК Сотрудник,
       |   Командировка.Организация КАК Организация,
       |   Командировка.ДатаНачала КАК ДатаНачала,
       |   Командировка.ДатаОкончания КАК ДатаОкончания,
       |   Командировка.МестоНазначения КАК МестоНазначения,
       |   Командировка.ОрганизацияНазначения КАК ОрганизацияНазначения,
       |   Командировка.Основание КАК Основание,
       |   Командировка.Цель КАК Цель,
       |   Командировка.КомандировкаЗаСчетСредств КАК КомандировкаЗаСчетСредств,
       |   Командировка.Руководитель КАК Руководитель,
       |   Командировка.ДолжностьРуководителя КАК ДолжностьРуководителя,
       |   Командировка.Начисления.(
       |       Должность КАК Должность,
       |       Подразделение КАК Подразделение
       |   ) КАК Начисления
       |ИЗ
       |   Документ.Командировка КАК Командировка
       |ГДЕ
       |   И Командировка.Начисления.Должность = &Должность
       |   И Командировка.Начисления.Подразделение = &Подразделение";
   
   Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Должность" = Должность);
   Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Подразделение" = Подразделение);
   
   МассивРезультатовЗапроса = Запрос.ВыполнитьПакет();
   
   РезультатДанныеГолова = МассивРезультатовЗапроса[0];
   РезультатДанныеТело   = МассивРезультатовЗапроса[1];
   
   ВыборкаГолова = РезультатДанныеГолова.Выбрать();
   ВыборкаГолова.Следующий();
   
   ВыборкаТело = РезультатДанныеТело.Выбрать();
   ВыборкаТело.Следующий();
   
   //Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
       // Вставити обробку вибірки ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи
   //КонецЦикла;

   Макет = Документы.Командировка.ПолучитьМакет("Командировка");
        //Шапка
   ОбластьГолова = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Голова");
 ОбластьГолова.Параметры.Дата                          = Формат(ВыборкаГолова.Дата, "ДФ=dd.MM.yyyy"); 
 ОбластьГолова.Параметры.Номер                         = ВыборкаГолова.Номер;
       ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьГолова); 
       //таблиця
   ОбластьТело = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Тело");
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Сотрудник                       = ВыборкаТело.Сотрудник;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Организация                     = ВыборкаТело.Организация;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Подразделение                   = ВыборкаТело.Подразделение;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.ДатаНачала                      = ВыборкаТело.ДатаНачала;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.ДатаОкончания                   = ВыборкаТело.ДатаОкончания; 
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.МестоНазначения                 = ВыборкаТело.МестоНазначения;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.ОрганизацияНазначения           = ВыборкаТело.ОрганизацияНазначения;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Основание                       = ВыборкаТело.Основание; 
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Цель                            = ВыборкаТело.Цель;   
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.КомандировкаЗаСчетСредств       = ВыборкаТело.КомандировкаЗаСчетСредств;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Руководитель                    = ВыборкаТело.Руководитель;   
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.ДолжностьРуководителя           = ВыборкаТело.ДолжностьРуководителя;
 ОбластьТело.Параметры.Должность                       = ВыборкаТело.Должность;

       ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьТело); 
       //текст
 ОбластьТекст = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Текст");
       ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьТекст);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Как мне быть что нужно сделать чтобы переменные выводились на печатную форму

Answer (score 1):

Параметры запроса устанавливаются через запятую:

```
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Должность", Должность);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Подразделение", Подразделение);
```

Также проверьте как у вас объявлены переменные Должность и Подразделение, похоже что они недоступны в режиме сервера.